# Dart , Flutter How can I overcome this error? I want to get info from map to display it here

Tags: flutter, dart

I used the youtube player plugin for flutter.
It works just fine but when I try to link it to a map of youtube URLs it throws an error.

......................Only static members can be accessed in initializers.

```
[class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var videoURL = uRls[0]['1'].tostring();

  YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  Map uRls = {
    "1": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8X9_MgEdCg",
    "2": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3co3Tskjtg",
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(videoURL));

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Youtube Player"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>\[
              YoutubePlayer(
                controller: _controller,
                showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
              ),
            \],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}][2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty straight forward, do not access the uRls map before any method.

If you would do it in the initState you should be fine.

```
  YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  Map<String, String> uRls = {
    "1": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8X9_MgEdCg",
    "2": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3co3Tskjtg",
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    var videoURL = uRls[0];

    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(videoURL),
      flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
        autoPlay: true,
  )
);

    super.initState();
  }
```

I also cleaned the Map slightly because of the accessor.

Comment: Thanks a million, it worked just magic. However, I want your help to play the video inside the map. like this code  [  videoURL = uRls[0]['1'].tostring();  ]

Comment: I updated the answer with a Autoplay function. And please read more about Dart Maps.https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#maps

Comment: I know that I ask too much but can you give me a hand? If I want to create a button that changes the video each time I click it and it uses the data from (I). I want this to be displayed on an overlay layer.